# ODE series solution versus explicit solution problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, power-series

Let $a>0$, consider $y''+2a\cot(ax)y'-2a^2y=0$. Before solving explicitly, assume we are looking for a solution with a pole at $x=0$, so that $y(x) \sim \frac{y_0}{x}+y_1+y_2 x+...$ as $x\to 0$. Because $2a\cot(ax) \sim \frac{2}{x}$ the ODE becomes

$$\frac{2y_0}{x^3}+O(1)+\frac{2}{x} \left(-\frac{y_0}{x^2}+y_2+O(x) \right) - 2a^2 \frac{y_0}{x} + O(1) = 0$$

We see that the terms of order $x^{-3}$ cancel, and to cancel the terms of order $x^{-1}$ we need $y_2 - a^2 y_0 = 0$. Now the explicit solution of the ODE is $$y(x) = \frac{c_1 \sinh(ax) + c_2 \cosh(ax)}{\sin(ax)}$$

and we can compute $y_0 = \frac{c_2}{a}$ and $y_2 = \frac{2c_2 a}{3}$. So the condition $y_2 - a^2 y_0 = 0$ is not satisfied. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the $2 a \cot(ax) y'$ you should get a term $\left(2 y_2 + \frac{2}{3} a^2 y_0\right) x^{-1}$, and from the $-2a^2 y$ another $-2 a^2 y_0 x^{-1}$, so the condition for the $x^{-1}$ terms to cancel is $$2 y_2 - \frac{4}{3} a^2 y_0 = 0$$

Comment: Oh I forgot to consider more terms from the expansion of $\cot$. Thank you!